# Unable to log into Stack Exchange using Google account on Windows Phone

Tags: discussion, login, internet-explorer, google-openid, windows-phone

I tried to login into `webmasters.stackexchange.com` through my Google account, but I was unable to do so. When I clicked the "Log in using Google" option, nothing happened and I remained on the same login page.

Has anyone faced this problem before? Why is this happening?

I am using a Nokia Lumia 525.

Comment: I tried going to webmasters.stackexchange.com on my 920, tapped the "log in" link, tapped on "Log in using Google", and was correctly redirected to accounts.google.com which prompted me to log in with my Google account. Is this how you tried to log in? What was shown in the IE address bar after you tapped on "Log in using Google" and nothing happened? Were you even using IE? Can you use the other login options? Does the same thing happen on other Stack Exchange sites?